# How to pass data to Popup and how to read it in Popup

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am calling a popup on actioncolumn click

> ```
>  handler: function (view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row) {                            
>                         Ext.widget('Info').show();
>                     }
> ```

If i want to pass record.get('firstname') then how to do this?

at the same time how to read the sent data in afterrender

> ```
> var infoForm = Ext.define('App.view.Report.Info', {
> extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
> listeners: {
>     afterrender: function () {                  
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use below code to pass any key-value to widget

```
Ext.widget('Info',{
    'firstname' : record.get('firstname') 
}).show();
```

Later, you can use it in afterrender function by, "this.firstname"

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this-

```
handler: function (view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row) {
    var infoWin=Ext.widget('Info');
    infoWin.firstName=record.get('firstname');
    infoWin.show();
}


var infoForm = Ext.define('App.view.Report.Info', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
listeners: {
    afterrender: function (winObj) { 
        var firstName=winObj.firstName;
    }
}
```

Since after creating Info instance, its nothing but an Object and you can add the new properties runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formpanel in your widget and use `form.loadRecord(record)` for easy data loading in formelements. Here is an example:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/19oe

Alternative:

```
handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
    var record = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
    Ext.create('App.view.Report.Info', {
        record: record
    }).show();
}
```

After Render for widget:

```
Ext.define('App.view.Report.Info', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    listeners: {
    afterrender: function () {
        if (this.record) {
            console.log(this.record);
        }                
    }
}
```